# Use 'N at row start in SQL Server bulk statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am inserting data from a csv file into a SQL Server table using the bulk statement, there is some German characters in file, and I want to use 'N at start of the row (as we use it in insert statement).

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need N: this is for nvarchar columns.

The standard Latin1_General_CI_AS collation (includes varchar codepage) supports [German characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508.aspx) already in varchar columns.

Comment: i have used Latin1_General_CI_AS collation but still character are not displaying correctly.. for example "R+¦hrawiesen Ortsmitte" and "t+ñglich"

Comment: @Ishti: you need to set some flag/options for the bulk load then. For example, the C switch http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx